# Validation ASP Classic DDL

Tags: javascript, html, validation, asp-classic

Unfortinatly I need to use ASP classic...
I have a drop down list that I load from database, but i can validate it..I need to do validation with JavaScript

```
<select name= "ddlCategories">
                    <option value="-1">  choose
                        </option>
                    <%set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                    con.open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("WebData/DB.mdb") & ";"
                    set rs = con.Execute("Select * FROM Categories where mode=true")
                    while not rs.eof%>
                    <option value="<%=rs("CatID")%>"><%=rs("CategoryName")%></option>
                        <%rs.movenext
                        wend
                        rs.close
                    set rs= nothing
                    Con.close%>
</select>
```

-1 it is the default value, and in this value the validation need to work..

Hope you understand me, Thanks

This is the validation for the TextBox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidationAddCategory()
{
var cName = document.form.tbCategory.value;
if (cName== "")
    {
        alert("Please insert category name")
        return(false)
    }
    return ture 
}

function ValidationDelCategory() {
          var oForm = document.getElementById('admin');
          var oTemp, strErrors='';

          //check 1
          oTemp = document.getElementById('ddlCategories');
          if (oTemp.value=='-1') {
            strErrors+='- Please select a category\n';
          }

          //put more checks here for any other validation, add to strErrors

          if (strErrors) {
            alert('There were errors:\n'+strErrors);
         }

       }

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have a form to validate before submitting...
In the example below, the form id is assumed to be "myForm" and the submit button is

```
<form id="myForm" ...
```

actually an input type="button" with an onclick of "checkSend();"

```
<input type="button" onclick="checkSend();" value="submit">
```

Also the select now has an Id of "ddlCategories"

The javascript for in the webpage head is as follows:

```
<script>
   function checkSend() {
      var oForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
      var oTemp, strErrors='';

      //check 1
      oTemp = document.getElementById('ddlCategories');
      if (oTemp.value=='-1') {
        strErrors+='- Please select a category\n';
      }

      //put more checks here for any other validation, add to strErrors

      if (strErrors) {
        alert('There were errors:\n'+strErrors);
      } else {
        oForm.submit();
      }

   }
</script>
```

So for a demo here's a complete example (without the ASP bit)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
       function checkSend() {
          var oForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
          var oTemp, strErrors='';

          //check 1
          oTemp = document.getElementById('ddlCategories');
          if (oTemp.value=='-1') {
            strErrors+='- Please select a category\n';
          }

          //put more checks here for any other validation, add to strErrors

          if (strErrors) {
            alert('There were errors:\n'+strErrors);
          } else {
            alert('Submitting...'); //remove this - its for testing
            oForm.submit();
          }

       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
    <select id="ddlCategories" name="ddlCategories">
    <option value="-1">Please select a category</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option> <!-- To be replaced by ASP Classic generation -->
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="checkSend();" value="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wrote this..'var oForm = document.getElementById("form");
var oTemp, strErrors='';
var oTemp = document.getElementById("ddlCategories");
if(oTemp.value==-1)
 { 
  alert("Select category")
  return(false)
 }' and still it dosent work

Comment: please try the function as above, I have corrected a couple of typos now - sorry.

Comment: Dosent work..from TextBox the validation is working, But from ddl it dosent work

Comment: theres no textbox in the example.  Please try the demo Ive just added.

Comment: Without ASP its working..I know that there is no textbox, im just saying

Comment: it sounds like you may already have a validation routing working on something else?

Comment: I have validation on textBox at that asp page

Comment: The problem is then that I have given a solution for what I can see.. If I could see the validation routine for the textbox, then I could help you incorporate this validation is.

Comment: I edit the question and add the validation of the textbox..but how can the validation of the textbox to disturb the validation of the ddl?

Comment: Well Im guessing the you are button is calling the existing routine not mine?

Comment: how is ValidationAddCategory called? and did you add id="ddlCategories" to the select?